# In php, how to include the exact content (not string form) from another file?

Tags: php

Let be an annex file named `annex.txt` , whose content is: `"text1","text2","text3"`

Now, I have a php file which contains this line:

```
$alfa = array ("text1","text2","text3");
```

How can I include the array elements using the external file `annex.txt` ?

Something like this:

```
$alfa = array ( file_get_contents('/annex.txt') ) ;
```

But, in this variant, $alfa will have just one element: `$alfa[0]` , which includes all the text as a whole string. So, how can I obtain `$alfa[0] = "text1" , $alfa[1] = "text2" , $alfa[2] = "text3"` ?

I know the function `file()` returns an array, but I wouldn't like to use it. I want to use `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: you may use explode function of php

Answer (score 5):

You should use [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or [`str_getcsv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
$alfa = str_getcvs(file_get_contents('annex.txt'));
```

Comment: @MariusMarius So you should approve the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$alfa =  file_get_contents('annex.txt') ;
$pieces = explode(",", $alfa);
echo $pieces[0]; // text1
echo $pieces[1]; // text2
....
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$alfa = explode(',', file_get_contents('/annex.txt'));
```